# Do conditional Where filters use deferred execution?

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a query of the form

```
var query = from items in entityDb.TableName
            join requestedBy in entityDb.People on items.RequestedById equals requestedBy.PersonId in requestedByOuter
            from requestedBy in requestedByOuter.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select items;
```

Also assume this is a big query, 10 more joins.  Then I have a conditional filter

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(phaseFilter))
{
   query = query.Where(item => item.Phase == phaseFilter);
}
```

At this point I believe I have lost the advantages of deferred execution. With 1000's of results this can hurt performance.  Considering my query is, in reality, 50 lines of code, I prefer not to go...

```
if(phaseFilter not null)
  //50 lines....
else if(filter2 not null)
  //50 lines...
else if (filter2 not null and phaseFilter not null)
  //50 lines...
```

ugh.  Can I somehow have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, you don't lose it. The execution is still deferred, because `.Where` just returns an `IEnumerable<T>` that filters the `IEnumerable<T>` passed to it, and it's still deferred when you do that.

Comment: I think you meant IQueryable, not IEnumerable.

Comment: @usr: [`IQueryable<T> : IEnumerable<T>`.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

No, you do not lose deferred execution in your case.

You can amend the `IQueryable` by calling `Where` multiple times and the actual query will be executed when you enumerate `IQueryable`.

The above applies to other methods, like `OrderBy` for example.

Comment: All of the methods that return an `IEnumerable`, `IQueryable`, or something derived from one of the two, are deferred.  All of the methods that don't, aren't.